# MAAS - Layer 2/3 architecure

Tags: networking, server, maas, pxe

I'm curious about the various network architecures that can work with mass. The docs state two layouts ( flat and split ) but they are fairly sparse as to what those are.

Unfortunately, due to a new location I am limited to one network and the nodes aren't capable of vlan tagging the pxe side...

So the main question here is: can I run on only one subnet? That is serving all purposes... internet access, ipmi, pxe, etc.. etc..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

Use port forwarding for different services on the network, and create two IP scopes for separation in just one Subnet. You can also use different class of subnet, so 10, 172, and 192. You can use something like 172.31.0.1-249 and 172.24.241-249 to subnet it in one class. Port forwarding is easy, you should try to only use one service per port though.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps I asked slightly the wrong way. I'd like to used one NIC, one subnet to do all. I think you're suggesting putting two ips per interface?